SCID opening trainer - can't get it to re-start after successfully running it once
On scid version 5.2 Mac I was successful in getting the opening trainer to run once on my training database, but now when I try to re-start it, I get the "Repertoire Training" window then click Continue, then all I get is an "Opening Trainer" window with the only options to "Show Report" or "Abort". I don't see any way to get it start training. I've tried closing and opening SCID again to no avail. What am I doing wrong?
